# @Injectable doesn't work while @Inject works

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I ran into strange issue.

I got really simple service:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class EchoService {
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

   public makeCall(): Observable<any> {
       return this.httpClient.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to reuse it in my component:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EchoService } from './services/echo.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: `app.component.html`,
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   public response: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private echoService: EchoService) {}

   public ngOnInit(): void {
       this.response = this.echoService.makeCall();
   }
}
```

And... I am running into `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EchoService: (?).`

When I am switching from `@Injectable` to `@Inject`, everything works:

```
 constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

and in component:

```
 constructor(@Inject(EchoService) private echoService: EchoService) {}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "dom", "esnext" ]
  }
}
```

What's the case? Why `@Injectable` doesn't work, while `@Inject` works?

Answer (score 1):

The same situation. When I migrated project from Angular 5 to 7 version. For me works:

add to **tsconfig.json** -  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true

full tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2015",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": []
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been searching everywhere for this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `@NgModule` declaration maybe you miss the `HttpClientModule` from the `imports` list.

Comment: I have HttpClientModule in my @NgModule. As I wrote.. I cannot inject anything without @Inject(). Not only httpClient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should add reflect-metadata library.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata